# Getting the path of a file from the SaveFileDialog to a string

Tags: c#

In my form I have a button that launches the SaveFileDialog module. Then when I load a file, I want to save the path as a string and put that text into a text box on the form. I'm not sure how to do this, or even where to start?

Comment: be more specific in you question : provide more details

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx)?

Comment: Look for `saveFileDialog1.FileName` property. Can you show your code? How you are using SaveFileDialog?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem with your question is that you say when you "load a file", but you cannot load a file from the SaveFileDialog module. However, if you are opening a file via the OpenFileDialog module, then you are able to use this solution to get the directory path of the file you just loaded:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryPath))
                textBox1.Text = directoryPath;
        }
```

Otherwise, if you are wanting to get the file path of whatever file you saved originally, you can use pretty much the same solution to get the directory path:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryPath))
                textBox1.Text = directoryPath;
        }
```